# Bash : How to tail latest file in continuous loop

Tags: bash, tail, scraper

I am trying to write script that monitors log file and on specific error it performs certain function.
I got the main code working however stuck with one problem.
Application create new log file when system date changes (log file name pattern is LOG.NODE1.DDMMYYYY), how do I get my code to automatically switch to new file that is created. Following is my script so far,

```
#!/bin/sh

logfile=$(ls -t $DIR"/env/log/LOG"* | head -n 1)
echo $logfile
tail -f $logfile | while read LOGLINE
do

if [[  "${LOGLINE}" == *";A database exception has occurred: FATAL DBERR:  SQL_ERROR: ORA-00001: unique constraint (IX_TEST1) violated"* ]];

then
        #Do something

fi
done
```

Comment: Is the new file named identically to the previous one? If so, using `tail -F` will make `tail` follow on the new file.

Comment: Do you have inotify?

Comment: sorry I should have mention that , I don't have inotify

Comment: @Aaron , Unfortunately the date part of filename changes.

Comment: I guess then, polling for a new file each ? seconds is the option. Or do you know when the application changes to new log file, ie. when is `when system date changes`?

Comment: You can put a timeout on your `read` and look for newer files when it fails.

Comment: BTW, `ls -t` isn't safe to use in scripts. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for reasoning, and [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for alternatives.

Comment: This is tagged bash, but using a `/bin/sh` shebang. Those are two different scripting languages -- which one do you want an answer for? (Is it acceptable if an answer uses bash-only code, and thus requires the shebang to be changed to `#!/bin/bash`?)

Comment: How many different nodes are there? Are you worried about not finding all the exceptions? I would change it from "real time" to a cron-driven job that runs every few minutes. With that approach, you can check for the latest file, and remember the last line number seen so you can start off there for the next run.

Comment: In a real-world production environment, I'd want to have a tool like logstash that's tailing your logs and putting the events on a message bus, so you can have as many consumers processing them as you need (including a central log server, a search server for indexing, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ -- **NOT** /bin/sh

substring=";A database exception has occurred: FATAL DBERR:  SQL_ERROR: ORA-00001: unique constraint (IX_TEST1) violated"
newest=
timeout=10  # number of seconds of no input after which to look for a newer file

# sets a global shell variable called "newest" when run
# to keep overhead down, this avoids invoking any external commands
find_newest() {
  set -- "${DIR?The variable DIR is required}"/env/log/LOG*
  [[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]] || return 1
  newest=$1; shift
  while (( $# )); do
    [[ $1 -nt $newest ]] && newest=$1
    shift
  done
}

while :; do
  find_newest  # check for newer files
  # if the newest file isn't the one we're already following...
  if [[ $tailing_from_file != "$newest" ]]; then
    exec < <(tail -f -- "$newest")  # start a new copy of tail following the newer one
    tailing_from_file=$newest       # and record that file's name
  fi
  if read -t "$timeout" -r line && [[ $line = *"$substring"* ]]; then
    echo "Do something here"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks Charles that worked perfectly. I take your points and apologies  re. 'ls -t' and bash. this is required for test env. and where monitoring solutions are proving expensive.